# Uncalled React methods are being executed, how is that?

Tags: reactjs

I have stumbled upon this code in the [official React website](https://reactjs.org/) in the "A Stateful Component" section of the page.

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { seconds: 0 };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      seconds: state.seconds + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Seconds: {this.state.seconds}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

root.render(<Timer />);
```

What I want to ask is that in the code above there is no line there that's calling `componentDidMount()` method but the output still updates the `this.state.seconds` value. How is this happening both in the technical level (that is in a very detailed way) and in the high level (i.e. by abstracting the details and explaining it in an easy-to-understand way)?

Comment: _React_ calls that method, at the appropriate point in the [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class).

Comment: I tried debugging this in VSCode but everytime I tried to step-into/step-in or try to track the process, it takes me to react files that is very complicated to understand so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React's internals call `componentDidMount` when the component mounts.

For a somewhat similar example, in the code below, the click function runs (when there's a click) despite there not being `button.onclick()` anywhere in the code.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onclick = () => console.log('click');
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Above, the `onclick` is invoked by the browser when a click event occurs.

In React, the `componentDidMount` method on a component - if it exists - is invoked when the component mounts.

For another example, imagine that there's some library that you pass an object with methods to:

```
const objectToPass = {
  theFn() {
    console.log('fn running');
  }
};
theLibrary(objectToPass);
```

Despite the fact that you don't have `objectToPass.theFn()`, it would be trivial for the library to invoke the function:

```js
const theLibrary = obj => obj.theFn();

const objectToPass = {
  theFn() {
    console.log('fn running');
  }
};
theLibrary(objectToPass);
```

React is doing the same sort of thing, except that `componentDidMount` is called when the component mounts (is finished being inserted into the DOM).

Comment: So React kinda has this built-in conditions to know when to execute this methods, or so I thought? If so, where can I read this kind of stuff. I kinda want to know this things.

Comment: The docs help - see the link in the other answer, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount